# after making a custom module global, certain dependencies disappear

Tags: node.js, npm

I wrote my own Node.js module. I have not uploaded it to the npm registry yet, so to use it locally I make it global. However, when I run

```
npm install . -g
```

command, some packages that my module is dependant on, dissappear, and my another project where I use my module gives me an error on those packages, that they do not exist in

```
User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node-modules\myModuleName
```

Why they disappear and how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not answering the question, but a workaround is to use `link` -

```
cd <project_A>
npm link 
cd <project_B_to_call_project_A_from>
npm link project_A
```

What this will do is,

1) Create a global symlink to project_A

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\project_A -> path_to_project_A
```

2) Create a local symlink to project_A from project_B

```
project_B\node_modules\project_A -> C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\project_A
```